# php: file_get_contents is stripping out php code

Tags: php

I'm attempting to file_get_contents and output php code as a string *without* being rendered. The idea is to grab the raw un-rendered file contents so they can be edited in a textarea...

```
// file "foo.php" I'm needing the contents of
<h1>foo</h1>
<? include 'path/to/another/file' ?>

// php file that's calling the file_get_contents
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('foo.php');
?>
```

The above code is stripping out the php include in foo.php which outputs:

```
<h1>foo</h1>
```

Does anyone know how I can get foo.php contents as a raw un-rendered string where output will be?:

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<? include 'path/to/another/file' ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you viewed the resulting source to make sure the content is really gone?

Comment: What you did should work. The only situation I can think of that would fail is if you are accessing foo.php as an URL (http://domain/foo.php)...

Comment: Doh! Okay, it's showing up in source but not in the DOM??

Comment: Victor, yes it's a local file.

Comment: Charles, is there a method for the php code string to show up in DOM though?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is what you want, as @thisMayhem has answered below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know you can't get php content unless it's on the same server. 
Make sure you're trying to access a locally hosted file and not something remote and it should work.

Also if you try to echo code it will try to parse it, so pass it through `htmlspecialchars($source)` and it should work.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('file.php'));
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Would echo formatted source code of the php file, including comments and any other text in it **without being parsed**. And since it looks like it's important to you, I'd also say that it **shows in the DOM** of course since it's no longer code, now it's text. You can place it inside a container, style it and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks thisMayhem!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do :

```
<?php 

highlight_file('file.php');
// or alternatively
echo highlight_file('file.php',true);
```

And that will output the file like with `htmlspecialchars` and `file_get_content` but within `<code>` tags and with some syntax highlighting.

> [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) :
>
> > (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
> >
> > highlight_string — Syntax highlighting of a string
>
> [highlight_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) :
>
> > (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
> >
> > highlight_file — Syntax highlighting of a file

Comment: The answer from 2010 was a more complete, better answer. I don't think your answer really solves the exact problem the OP is looking for. See Juan Cortes' answer above.

Comment: @benny I was thinking "I'm attempting to file_get_contents and output php code as a string without being rendered" was exactly the point of the `highlight` instruction, and would be a useful tool for future users.