# file_get_contents cuts first 9 lines of the file

Tags: php, include

I want to include a code sample from a file without executing it.
But I have no idea why functions such as `fread()` or `file_get_contents()` cut first 9 lines of the included file.

Include without executing code (one of many ways I tried):

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "index_GD.php";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
echo "<pre><codesample>".$contents."</codesample></pre>";
fclose($handle);
?>
```

First 11 lines of the included file:

```
<?php

// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

function imagegradientellipse($image, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, $ic, $oc){
 $w = abs($w);
 $h = abs($h);
 $oc = array(0xFF & ($oc >> 0x10), 0xFF & ($oc >> 0x8), 0xFF & $oc);
 $ic = array(0xFF & ($ic >> 0x10), 0xFF & ($ic >> 0x8), 0xFF & $ic);
 $c0 = ($oc[0] - $ic[0]) / $w;
```

Output (first 11 lines):

```
 > 0x10), 0xFF & ($oc >> 0x8), 0xFF & $oc);
 $ic = array(0xFF & ($ic >> 0x10), 0xFF & ($ic >> 0x8), 0xFF & $ic);
 $c0 = ($oc[0] - $ic[0]) / $w;
 $c1 = ($oc[1] - $ic[1]) / $w;
 $c2 = ($oc[2] - $ic[2]) / $w;
 $i = 0;
 $j = 0;
 $is = ($w<$h)?($w/$h):1;
 $js = ($h<$w)?($h/$w):1;
 while(1){
```

Comment: you can simply use php file('path to file') function to get the content of the file without parsing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use htmlspecialchars http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
echo htmlspecialchars($contents);
```

If you check the page source, you will probably find all your text there although the browser does not display it.

There was a similar question:
[php: file_get_contents is stripping out php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072674/php-file-get-contents-is-stripping-out-php-code)